# Q-Quote in execute immediate PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I have following Update statement:

```
UPDATE COL_VAL SET DESC_VALUE=q'['TOM','JOHN','MARIE','VANI','PUTIN']' WHERE TYPE_NAME||TYPE='OLDHOL' ;
```

When I put above q-qoute in execute immediate, PL/SQL is not able to recognize syntax.

```
DECLARE
upd_stmnt varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
    upd_stmnt := q'[UPDATE COL_VAL SET DESC_VALUE=q'['TOM','JOHN','MARIE','VANI','PUTIN']' WHERE     TYPE_NAME||TYPE='OLDHOL']';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE upd_stmnt;
END;
/
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

seems that you can't nest q quoted strings, please try this one

```
DECLARE
  upd_stmnt varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
    upd_stmnt := q'[UPDATE COL_VAL SET DESC_VALUE = '''TOM'',''JOHN'',''MARIE'',''VANI'',''PUTIN''' WHERE TYPE_NAME || TYPE='OLDHOL']';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE upd_stmnt;
END;
/
```

Comment: Agreed, this is a workaround. But what if this statement is coming dynamically in a routine.

What I mean is these statements are stored in a table and the routine simply queries this table and executes them via execute immediate.

I can't think currently of modifying these statements since there are thousands of them.

Would appreciate any solutions.

Comment: please, could you provide example of row in this table?

Comment: Concat CHR(39) if you need to tie wrap a parameter or a set of strings, and itCHR(39)s cleaner :)